# multibib package gving me an error "Extra \fi"

Tags: errors, multibib

I'm trying to use the multibib package and my MWE is pretty much identical to the one in the manual but I keep getting an error. It says `! Extra \fi`

The weird thing is, even I don't do anything in the body it still shows up. Just having the line `\usepackage{multibib}` in the preamble with nothing else changed throws up this error. Is there a bug or am I missing something?

Here is the MWE anyway

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn,balance,superscriptaddress,floats,showpacs,a4paper]{revtex4}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage[left=18mm,right=18mm,top=22mm,bottom=22mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multibib}

\begin{document}
\title{Blah}

\author{ABC}
\email{ABC}
\altaffiliation{ABC}
\affiliation{ABC}


\maketitle


\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

I also tried the full version

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn,balance,superscriptaddress,floats,showpacs,a4paper]{revtex4}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage[left=18mm,right=18mm,top=22mm,bottom=22mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{ltex}{Secondary References}

\begin{document}

Main text with \cite{Primary Ref 1}
\bibliography{bib}

Secondary text with \citeltex{Secondary Ref 1}
\bibliographyltex{bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get no error if I run pdftex on your MWE (by the way you don't need to load `graphics` if you have `graphicx` and probably don't want `epsf` either)

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to add in the title. If I remove the title, it works fine. My MWE now doesn't work. Thank you for the advice on redundant packages.

Comment: You want `\title` not `title` then the error goes

Comment: Note that `revtex4-1` has a very peculiar way to set the references and making `multibib` run with the class seems quite difficult.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a backslash: You want `\title` not `title` then the error goes.

The reason is that the default value stored for the `revtex` title does some tests (hence the `\if..\fi` code) and makes a warning that `\title` has not been used. Some code somewehre is not expecting the testing `\if` code to still be in the title value.

Comment: Thanks but there's still some trouble. Perhaps egreg is right, Revtex and multibib don't seem to work together well. I updated the MWE again with the author list and it shows the same error with `\email{...}` and `\altaffiliation{...}`