# Having Multiple Bibliographies using AIP document class in Overleaf

Tags: bibliographies, document-classes, overleaf, multibib

I am finalizing a document for an AIP journal on overleaf, so I am using the aip documentclass.

```
\documentclass[%
 aip,
% jmp,
% bmf,
% sd,
% rsi,
 amsmath,amssymb,
%preprint,%
 reprint,%
%author-year,%
%author-numerical,%
% Conference Proceedings
]{revtex4-1}
```

I also have this in my preamble to setup my bibliography.

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{New}{The other list}

\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{appendix}{supplementary material}{supplementary materials}
\Crefname{appendix}{Supplementary Material}{Supplementary Materials}
```

In my main document, I have a bibliography at the end. This works fine, but in my two appendices I want to also have a bibliography, one for each appendix (labeled supplementary material).

```
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\bibliography{references}
```

When I insert my first appendix, I try to insert the second bibliography.

```
\clearpage
\input{Writing/SupA}
```

*in Supplementary Material A now...* after I have my text I want to have the second bibliography that still is titled References.

```
\bibliographystyleNew{plain}
\bibliographyNew{referencesA}
```

But when I try to use `\citeNew{}` in the text of Supplementary Material A nothing happens. There's not even an error message. Maybe I'm setting it up wrong? Here is the link describing how to use `multibib` on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/multibib). **I've already asked Overleaf for technical support, but have yet to hear back; I posted this here to hopefully get a quicker reply.**

Ultimately I will need to do something similar for Supplementary Material B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Overleaf? multibib just seems not compatible with revtex.

[multibib package gving me an error "Extra \fi"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154188/multibib-package-gving-me-an-error-extra-fi#comment352380_154188)

[Multiple bibliographies in Revtex 4.1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503914/multiple-bibliographies-in-revtex-4-1)

Comment: yes I found that out recently